# Upload Map information to Firebase - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am new to Firebase Storage. How do I send map information (latitude,longitude,radius) to be stored in Firebase? The information would be gathered from a pin dropped on the map by a user. That user would then send it to another user. The information in only seen by the sender and receiver. Each user should be able to send out multiple locations to different people. It is not their current location. But instead a location the sending user chooses.

Answer (score 0):

This code is assumming that that you already retrieve your user coordinate. If you have any other questions let me know

```
let currentUserLocation = myLocation.coordinate


            let coords: [String: Double] = [
                "lat": self.currentUserLocation!.latitude,
                "long": self.currentUserLocation!.longitude,
            ]

            let currentUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
            self.dbFir.child("users/\(currentUser!)/").updateChildValues(coords, withCompletionBlock: { (error, dbFir) in
                if error != nil {

                    error?.localizedDescription

                } else {

                }

            })
```

Comment: How would I retrieve my users coordinate from a map? Not their current location but a location that they dropped a pin.

Comment: are you currently using Google map or Apple Map?

Comment: Apple Map. I imported the MapKit and CoreLocation

Comment: Me personally I prefer Google Maps, I think they documentation is well explained and they also have a method to retrieve the tapped coordinate ` mapView:didTapAtCoordinate:`. Its also much simpler to use then MK.

Comment: How would I import that. I have the map shown in my app

Comment: Please follow the documentation here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/get-api-key I think this will open new ideas to you once you fully understand how it work.

Comment: Also view the class and methods list to see of all the possibilities of the API

Comment: Thank you for your help.